# How send message to one specific contact on whatsapp from phonegap?

Tags: cordova, whatsapp

I'm begginer on Phonegap. I'd like send message to one specific contact that I config to open using HTML5. For example, same one chat.

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. I have the same issue. I want to open a specific whatsapp contact that my user can send a message to it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, this a cordova plugin for whatsapp

https://github.com/ranjitpandit/whatsapp-phonegap-plugin

Comment: last commit was 2 years ago and seems to be android only.